# Science Fiction novel where humans had multiple personalities called "Daemons"

Tags: story-identification

Science fiction novel where humans were like gods.  They had multiple personalities that they called "daemons" or something similar.  Main character was a bit of a fop, but reportedly brilliant.  He got kidnapped and some of of his daemons developed in a subconscious way to be significantly grittier and more survival oriented, eventually freeing him.

I loved it and need to see if there were sequels, but can't find it.

Comment: Another novel employing the daemon angle is the "His Dark Materials" series by Phillip Pullman. "“But suppose your dæmon settles in a shape you don't like?

Well, then, you're discontented, en't you? There's plenty of folk as'd like to have a lion as a dæmon and they end up with a poodle. And till they learn to be satisfied with what they are, they're going to be fretful about it. Waste of feeling, that is.

But it didn't seem to Lyra that she would ever grow up.” 
― Philip Pullman, The Golden Compass"

Comment: Thanks!  I did like that one, but it actually confused my search, because "daemon" was the spelling I was using.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It’s [*Aristoi*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aristoi_(novel)) by Walter Jon Williams. There are no sequels, but Williams was very much channelling early Roger Zelazny at the time, and if you liked it I suggest checking him out.

> The Aristoi (and some others) can split their minds into daimones, or
>   "limited personalities", all which can operate as independent mental
>   entities guided by the will of the main 'self' of the Aristos.
>
> [...]
>
> Gabriel and his companions are captured and imprisoned. [...] However,  their plan is foiled when a previously hidden
>   sub personality of Gabriel, that he dubs The Voice, uses his computer
>   privileges to escape. Gabriel manages to defeat Saito and escape along
>   with his friends.

Comment: Thanks for this; I am a fan of early Zelazny so now I want to read this.

Comment: @OrganicMarble _Knight Moves_, also by Williams, is even more Zelaznyish.

Comment: Thank you!!  That's exactly it.  I couldn't find it at least in part because I couldn't remember how he spelled "daimones".  You are amazing and quick!

Comment: The Williams novel that probably comes closest in style to Aristoi is *Implied Spaces*, which is also quite Zelaznyesque.